# Should I use the application code inside the docker images or in volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am working on a Devops project. I want to find the perfect solution.
I have a conflict between two solutions. should I use the application code inside the docker images or in volumes?

Comment: Put code in images (so you can test the code, and know what version is running). Put data in volumes.

Answer (score 4):

Your code should almost never be in volumes, developer-only setups aside (and even then).  This is doubly true if you have a setup like a frequent developer-only Node setup that puts the `node_modules` directory into a Docker-managed anonymous volume: since Docker will refuse to update that directory on its own, the primary effect of this is to cause Docker to ignore any changes to the `package.json` file.

More generally, in this context, you should think of the image as a way to distribute the application code.  Consider clustered environments like Kubernetes: the cluster manager knows how to pull versioned Docker images on its own, but you need to work around a lot of the standard machinery to try to push code into a volume.  You should not need to both distribute a Docker image and also separately distribute the code in the image.

I'd suggest using host-directory mounts for injecting configuration files and for storing file-based logs (if the container can't be configured to log to stdout).  Use either host-directory or named-volume mounts for stateful containers' data (host directories are easier to back up, named volumes are faster on non-Linux platforms).  Do not use volumes at all for your application code or libraries.

(Consider that, if you're just overwriting all of the application code with volume mounts, you may as well just use the base `node` image and not build a custom image; and if you're doing that, you may as well use your automation system (Salt Stack, Ansible, Chef, *etc.*) to just install Node and ignore Docker entirely.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's very clear.